# Выражение "опционально"

Tags: пунктуация

Надо ли выделять запятыми наречие "опционально"? В первый раз столкнулась с этим выражением...

Опционально, для затворов возможно изготовление манжеты...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не вводное слово, поэтому его не нужно выделять запятыми.

Answer (score 1):

Это наречие, запятая не нужна. Опционально - значит на выбор.